# Can't pause mediaplayer from adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I have the listview in my activity. Each listview item contains play/pause buttons, and these buttons start audio playback by calling activity method, like MainActivity.play(), but when i press stop button, it doesn't work. Why?

I tried to put pause button on the Activity and it works great.

Here is my button's onClickListener, which is in adapter

```
            view.findViewById(R.id.btnPause).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((MainActivity)context).pause();
                }
            });
```

Here is pause method from activity

```
    public void pause() {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
    }
```

This is my whole adapter

```
public class lvAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<m> objects;
    lvAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<m> products) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = products;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    // кол-во элементов
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    // элемент по позиции
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    // id по позиции
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // пункт списка
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
                view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.audioItem, parent, false);
        }
        final View finalView = view;
        view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir() + "/voices/" + objects.get(position).t);
                    if (file.exists()) {
                            ((MainActivity)ctx).play(file.getPath());
                    }
                }
            });
        view.findViewById(R.id.btnPause).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity)context).pause();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    m getProduct(int position) {
        return ((m) getItem(position));
    }
}
```

And it is just doesn't work. mediaplayer is not pausing.

Comment: Provide your entire adapter

Comment: @HB. I tried to put code for play and pause into runnables, and now it works perfectly. is it good solution?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that placing the play/pause in runnables makes it work. This tells me that something is taking time to get called. When do you prepare your mediaPlayer?

Comment: Please provide your play method